# Access contents of div elements based on their window position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two div elements on my page which are positioned in such a way that both divs are at the same distance from the top of the page but are separated by some horizontal distance. Both div elements have some text entered into them dynamically using Javascript/jQuery. I want to access the text within the two divs in such a way that I can perform some action when both divs contain the same (or matching) text. Is there a way to do this based on the position of the divs using Javascript/jQuery ? I cannot use the obvious solution of id's because of certain restraints.

Comment: Can you assign unique class for each element?

Comment: A unique class for each div? I suppose I can. And after I've done that?

Comment: Acess the elemnts using class

Comment: Hmm no well I don't think I can do that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say that the two divs you want are at 100, 100 and 100, 300 :

```
var all_divs = $("div");
var div1;
var div2;

for (var i=0; i<all_divs.length; i++){
    var o = $(all_divs[i]).offset();

    if (o.top == 100 && o.left == 100) {
        div1 = all_divs[i];
    }

    if (o.top == 100 && o.left == 300) {
        div2 = all_divs[i];
    }
}

var polling = setInterval(function(){
    if ($(div1).text() == $(div2).text()) {
        perform_some_action();
        clearInterval(polling);
    }
}, 500);
```

Comment: This looks brilliant. But why the setInterval?

Comment: You said that the DIVs' contents updated dynamically, so I'm not sure if you can trigger this when they update or you just have to keep checking.  The `setInterval` might not be necessary if you check the contents when you update the DIVs.

Comment: Yeah it isn't necessary in my case but it doesn't cause any problem either ways so I'll keep it :). Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to identify your divs based on their position use `.offset()`

-[Api documentation for .offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Comment: I was thinking about that too. But I was wondering if it provides the same results for all browsers.

Comment: From what I can see with a quick search... offset should work across most browsers. Although IE, as is usually the case, may present some problems. Research it a little there are lots of solutions out there.